# how to know the mysql update query status

Tags: mysql

I've a table with columns sal,id . suppose for the id 101,I'm updating the sal. How do I select 1 if that row is updated successfully? Suppose if any error is happened while updating(like the id is not there) then I need to select 0 as output. In oracle proc it is as follows.I need the same in mysql proc  
 Begin Proc   
 counter int default 0;  
 update tbname set sal=xxx where id=xxx;  
  counter++;  
  select counter from dual;//will gives me 1.  
 Exception when no_data_found then   
select counter from dual;//will gives me zero End proc

Comment: I'm making it more clear. Its a mysql stored proc. The proc should return 1 if the row is updated and 0 if not updated. I want solution at  DB level.

Answer (score 2):

try `mysql_affected_rows()`

in http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

it will return the number of affected rows if 0 then no row updated

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm making it more clear. Its a mysql stored proc. The proc should return 1 if the row is updated and 0 if not updated. I want solution at  DB level.

Comment: you can use row_count() in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

Comment: it's similer to mysql_affected_rows

Answer (score -1):

```
$verify="UPDATE mytable SET producename='dddaaa' WHERE username='$username'";
mysql_query($verify,$mysqlconnect);

-- or -- 

$verify="UPDATE mytable SET producename='dddaaa' WHERE produceid='3'  ";
mysql_query($verify,$mysqlconnect);
```

Comment: Not correct ans.. in above ans how do you know rows are updated or not?

Comment: Where in this answer is the answer to the question "How do I select 1 if that row is updated successfully? "?